# Adding item to end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
List_cell *currPtr = list_first_;

if(list_first_ == nullptr){

    list_first_ = new_cell;
}
else{

    currPtr = list_first_;
    while(currPtr->next != nullptr){
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
        currPtr->next = new_cell;
    }
}
```

what is wrong with this? It doesn't seem to go in the while loop at all... Thanks for help!

Comment: Please show your full code. What is new_cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to set currPtr->next to be new_cell until you get to the end of the list, otherwise you'll just add new_cell after the first element in the list, and then lose whatever was already in the list.

```
List_cell *currPtr = list_first_;

if(list_first_ == nullptr){

    list_first_ = new_cell;

}
else{

    currPtr = list_first_;
    while(currPtr->next != nullptr){
        currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
    currPtr->next = new_cell;
}
```

will add new_cell on to the list only when you reach the end.

Comment: Though I would of course recommend you use list from the standard library rather than creating your own except for learning purposes.

Comment: This is a part of my school project which requires me to use linked list :(